# Magento Form Block not rendered

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to make a real grid based on a magento model. 
Everything is working well on the read part, but the form to edit isnt rendered and i have no errors in logs.
I noticed that my _prepareForm function is never called, but I don't know why.

My form call in controller:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $this->_initAction();

    // Get id if available
    $id  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact_request_id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('whatever_booking/contactRequest');

    if ($id) {
        // Load record
        $model->load($id);

        // Check if record is loaded
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('This Contact Request no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        }
    }

    $this->_title($model->getId() ? $model->getName() : $this->__('New Contact Request'));

    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getContactRequestData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model->setData($data);
    }

    Mage::register('whatever_booking', $model);

    $this->_addBreadcrumb($id ? $this->__('Edit Contact Request') : $this->__('New Contact Request'), $id ? $this->__('Edit Contact Request') : $this->__('New Contact Request'));
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('whatever_booking/adminhtml_contactRequest_edit')->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/*/save'));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
} 

protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('customer/ContactRequest')
        ->_title($this->__('Whatever Booking'))->_title($this->__('Contact Request'));

    return $this;
}
```

And my form  :

```
class Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    /**
     * Init class
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('whatever_booking_contactRequest_form');
        $this->setTitle($this->__('Contact Request Information'));
        //when i var dump here i see that my controller called this function
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        var_dump('here');
        die; // this var dump is never reached
    }
}
```

edit block

```
class Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    /**
     * Init class
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'whatever_booking';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_contactRequest';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', $this->__('Save Request'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', $this->__('Delete Request'));
    }

    /**
     * Get Header text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('contact_request')->getId()) {
            return $this->__('Edit Request');
        }
        else {
            return $this->__('New Request');
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // mage log is passing here when i display one
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Your controller seems to miss a call to $this->loadlayout(), is that in _initaction()?

Comment: I edited the post with my _initAction, and yes it is called there, so it isnt the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: 
in your controller load the form directly, however it can be better to pass by the container before, you still can call it that way:

```
  $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_contactRequest_edit_form'))
       ->_setActiveMenu('customer/ContactRequest');
```

then in your booking xml file for layout :

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_contactRequest_edit_form>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="whatever_booking/adminhtml_contactRequest_edit_form" name="aeschbachbooking.form" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_contactRequest_edit_form>
</layout>
```

Comment: This seems to work but as you said it might be better to pass by the container. I will wait to see if someone make it work with the container. Thanks

Comment: Also i don't have the buttons of container if I reach directly the form

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you're adding an edit block, not the form block:

```
<?php
// ...
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('whatever_booking/adminhtml_contactRequest_edit')->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/*/save'));
// ...
```

Is this `Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Edit` block a proper `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container`? The form container is responsible for finding the proper form to load. It does this in its `_prepareLayout` function:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
        $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Also, I wonder if the camel-cased `ContactRequest` part is throwing Magento for a loop. Try making that part of your block `Contactrequest` and see if that works (you'll have to rename its folder and such).

Comment: Hi, my Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Edit is extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container.
I tried to override _prepareLayout just to see if it is called, and yes my code is going through this function ( just calling its parent) in Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Edit

Comment: for the camel case i guess it is passing well because i came in this form from a grid and its grid container which had the same structure
Whatever_Booking_Block_ContactRequest and Whatever_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_ContactRequest_Grid, so i think it is not the problem either Magento isnt bringing problem with camel case in this area, it is just not good to use underscores :)